# mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState) in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I was reading the documentation and it says:

> When using the API in fully interactive mode, users of the MapView class must forward the following activity lifecycle methods to the corresponding methods in the MapView class: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), onSaveInstanceState(), and onLowMemory().

I managed to implement every lifecycle methods except mapView.onCreate() in the fragment's onCreate() method. The app crashes when I implement this:

```
    private lateinit var mapView: MapView    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView) as MapView
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

From my understanding, it is because the view has not be initialized in onCreate() that's why findViewById would not work. Is this something wrong with the documentation?

Comment: in Fragments you should put it in oncreateview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead initialize your `mapView` in Fragment's `onCreateView`like this (Java):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_page, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this); //this is important

    return v;
}
```